# How to submit Jsp Page with encoding multipart/form-data

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

I am submitting html form with encoding (multipart/form-data)
I have following fields in Jsp Page
First name
Last Name
file name to be uploaded

file is uploaded perfectly
how to get first name and last name ?
I want to save in database.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the same API to extract the text fields as you've used to get the file content. Assuming that you're using the (de facto standard) [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) for this, then you need to act on whenever `FileItem#isFormField()` returns `true`.

```
try {
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
            String fieldvalue = item.getString();
            // ... (do your job here)
        } else {
            // Process form file field (input type="file").
            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
            String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
            InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
            // ... (do your job here)
        }
    }
} catch (FileUploadException e) {
    throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)